# How to get source code of a package in ubuntu for a specific version

Tags: apt, package-management, source

For example,

```
sudo apt-get source bash
```

downloads the source code for the latest bash package version (5.0). How do I get the source code for an older version of the package (e.g. 4.3).

Is there some way to specify version in the 'apt-get source' command or any other commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the source from the [GNU directory](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/):

```
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.3.tar.gz
```

Using `apt` it will download the current available version in Ubuntu
repositories.

By adding Xenial source repository , you can download the `4.3-14` :

```
printf "deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main" |\
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-src.list
sudo apt update
apt source bash=4.3-14ubuntu1.4
```